# Remove Filtered Data VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that filters data and I would like to delete the data in the column. The code I have (below) does this but it deletes all of the data in the column. I require the data to be removed so the cell is still blank not deleted.

```
Range("A1:AC1").AutoFilter
Range("A1:AC1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0.00", Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("Q4:Q1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Comment: ??? `Range("Q4:Q1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear` ???

Comment: you do not need the first autofilter code line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
Range("Q4:Q1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

with:

```
Range("Q4:Q1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
```

Comment: @LukeTurnbull Remember, if it worked, please mark as accepted answer so others would know :)